# Assignment to deleted/uninitialized object

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, destructor, unions

I have a class like this

```
struct foo {
    bool type;
    union {
        struct { std::string s; };
        struct { std::function<std::string(void)> f; };
    };
};
```

I need to have assignment operators defined, but when I'm assigning different type I'm basicly assigning to uninitialized field (I know I have to explicitly call destructor first).

My guess is that such assignment is undefined behavior, since I don't know if assignment of string or function doesn't reuse some fields.

How can I do this correctly without invoking any undefined behavior?

I am limited to C++11.

Comment: Isn't `type` there specifically to tell you which field is active?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux the problem happens when i want to assign to object with different active type than the one i'm assigning

Comment: Can you show the assignment you believe to UB?

Comment: Why not to use `boost::variant`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My guess is that such assignment is undefined behavior, since I don't know if assignment of string or function doesn't reuse some fields.

Good guess! Assignment always has as its precondition that the left-hand side is actually an object of that type. If we don't have an object on the left-hande side, all bets are off.

> How can I do this correctly without invoking any undefined behavior?

Construction! When you don't have an object, the only way to get an one is to create it. And since we want to create it in a specific location, that's placement new.

I am not sure why you are wrapping your types in an extra struct, you want to do this:

```
union U {
    U() { }
    ~U() { }

    std::string s;
    std::function<std::string(void)> f;
} u;
```

With that, your assignment operator would be:

```
foo& operator=(foo const& rhs) {
    if (type) {
        if (rhs.type) {
            u.s = rhs.u.s;
        } else {
            u.s.~string();
            new (&u.f) std::function<std::string(void)>(rhs.u.f);
        }
    } else {
        if (!rhs.type) {
            u.f = rhs.u.f;
        } else {
            u.f.~function();
            new (&u.s) std::string(rhs.u.s);
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

You'll want to refactor some of that to support move-assignment without lots of duplication, but that's the rough idea.

Comment: Im wrapping types in structs because either c++11 or just vs2012 doesn't allow me to make union with types that have copy constructor

Comment: @Ryba vs2012 is not very C++11 complaint.  You should upgrade to get better conformance.

Comment: @NathanOliver i would use gcc and c++17 and proper std::variant if i wasn't stuck with vs2012

Comment: @Ryba you got locked out by c++03 restriction supported by MS. Funny enough you cheat here, because struct that contain nontrivial members is non-trivial, but anonymous struct, a non-standard feature of MS C++, is one that is not. That sound like bug\misfeature use.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie so is there a proper c++11 way to make a variant that supports non-trivial members?

Comment: @Ryba Yes, you use a union - you just explicitly provide a constructor and destructor for that union that does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, anonymous structs are ill-formed in C++. You could use instead for example:

```
union {
    std::string s;
    std::function<std::string(void)> f;
};
```

> My guess is that such assignment is undefined behaviour

Correct.

> How can i do this correctly without invoking any undefined behaviour?

You could use the tagged union pattern. You appear to already have a `type` member. You could use that to designate which member is active. If you had other plans for that member, simply add a new one.

Once you can use a struct member to check which union member is active, you can destroy the active member and then copy construct a previous inactive union member, and finally update `type` to signify the new active member.

---

That said, you can save some time by using a pre-existing generic implementation of a tagged union. There's one in [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html) for example.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 is kind enough to not even allow this. As your union contains fields with non trivial constructors and destructors, `struct foo` has implicitely deleted default constructor and destructor.

My old  clang version 3.4.1 (with option std=c++11) chokes when I try to create a `struct foo` with:

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted
```

and

```
 note: default constructor of 'foo' is implicitly deleted because variant field has a non-trivial default constructor.
```

And if I try to manually initialize a `struct foo` with (I slightly changed `foo` to avoid anonymous fields):

```
...
struct foo {
    bool type;
    union {
        struct { std::string s; } s;
        struct { std::function<std::string(void)> f; } f;
    };
};

int main() {
    foo bar { .s = {"a"}};
    ...
```

I get another error (as expected):

```
error: attempt to use a deleted function
    foo bar { .s = {"a"}};
```

and

```
note: destructor of 'foo' is implicitly deleted because variant field 's' has a non-trivial destructor
        struct { std::string s; } s;
                                  ^
```

Comment: Nah, first what you should get `anonymous types declared in an anonymous union are an extension [-Wnested-anon-types]` because standard doesn't allow that. With `-std=c++11 -pedantic` code should work without anonymous structs.